# How to configure Eclipse to show coordinates of cursor?

Tags: eclipse

I can't figure out how to get Eclipse to show coordinates of the cursor. I can get Eclipse to show line numbers next to each line, but that's not what I want.

Thank you,

ilyia

Comment: in which file you want to get the coordinates. Java, XML or HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a "bug" that probably won't be fixed. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391731

Answer (score 0):

At least in the Java and XML editors, Eclipse 3.6 shows the cursor row and column in the window toolbar without me having to configure anything.

Comment: The coordinates are in fact there when editing Java and regular XML files. I am facing the original problem in the context of editing a pom.xml file. The Maven plugin offers the option to edit the source of the pom, but this editor window is not the same as a regular XML editor, there are no coordinates visible below in the status bar.